# cannot read property 'categories' of null

Tags: node.js, api

Any help will be highly appreciated
I'm having an error in my terminal and I cannot identify what's wrong with my code.

**My Controller**

```js
module.exports.addCategory = (params) => {
    return User.findById(params.userId)
        .then((user, err) => {
            if (err) return false
            user.categories.push(params)
            return user.save()
                .then((updatedUser, err) => {
                    return err ? false : true
                })
                .catch(err => {
                    console.log(err)
                })
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
        });
}
```

**My Routes**

```js
router.post(
    '/',
    auth.verify,
    (req, res) => {
        CategoryController.addCategory(req.body).then(result => res.send(result))
    }
)
```

**Error on terminal**

[image: terminal error]

Comment: The error means that the value of `user` is `null`.

Comment: what is the result console.log(user)?

Comment: @FelixKling How's that happening even I'm logged in?

Comment: Maybe `params.userId` doesn't have the correct value?

Comment: @WilliamWang what line should i put the console.log?

Comment: right after `.then((user, err) => {`

Comment: @WilliamWang console.log(user) is null on my terminal..